# What does "$@" do when running a python script?

Tags: python, sh

I say this at the end of a script execution

https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/OpenNIR/blob/master/scripts/pipeline.sh

`python -m onir.bin.pipeline "$@"`

I wonder what it does

Comment: It expands the the parameters you passed to the script. So if you wrote `bash pipeline.sh foo bar qux`, then it will call it with `python -m onir.bin.pipeline foo bar qux`.

Comment: Nothing to do with Python